# gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease Failed

Tags: android, gradle, apk, build.gradle

Can anyone helep me on this while running below command build fails
**gradle assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/ubuntu/clarks-select-android/app/build.gradle' line: 10
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.322 secs